# Taking up a fraction of a Row space

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I take up additional space not in use?

I am building a widget based on a Rest response.

Sometimes I might get a list of 3 items. Sometimes there could be only 1 or 2.

If there is 3 items, I want them in a row taking up all space like the following.

(No issues in achieving this)

[image]

But if there is only 1 or 2 data, I only want them to take up a 1/3 or 2/3 of the space as follows.

[image]

[image]

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have currently where I have a method which validates how many items I have.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
        Expanded(child: CustomWidget()), // at least 1 item will exist
        logicToCheckIfMoreThanXItemExists(count: 1) ? Expanded(child: CustomWidget()) : Text('Test1'),
        logicToCheckIfMoreThanXItemExists(count: 2) ? Expanded(child: CustomWidget()) : Text('Test2'),
    ],
)
```

No issues if I have 3 items. But if it is 1 or 2, it ends up taking up all space. Thus just for testing, added Text Widgets.

I could place in fake Widgets to take up the space or play with flex value for Expanded and add a fake child widget there.

Looking for a cleaner alternative. Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you the Spacer widget. Which is basically an expanded without a child